# Maxima, minima and inexistence of gradient of $f(x,y) = min\{f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider:

$f_1(x,y) = -27x^2+27x−27y^2 −54y−31,$

$f_2(x,y) = −27x^2 −54x −27y^2 −54y −58$

How to determine the set of points $(x,y)$ where the gradient of

$f(x,y) = min\{f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y)\}$

does not exist?

Also: how to find local (and global) maxima and minima of $f(x,y)$?

What I´ve been able to do so far?

I supposed (just not sure how to prove it) that at the intersection of $f_1$ and $f_2$ the gradient will not exist. So I found the point $(-\frac{1}{3},y)$ to be a parabola in $R^3$ where the gradient of $f(x,y)$ will not exist.

Regarding maxima and minima, how do I apply the rule of finding where the gradient equals zero in order to later analyse the Hessian matrix? I don´t have a single expression for $f(x,y)$. I´m confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

We can improve the way the function $f$ is written by the following expression:
$$\min\{f_{1},f_{2}\}=\frac{f_{1}+f_{2}}{2}-\frac{|f_{1}-f_{2}|}{2}$$Then,
\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}^{2}&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto f(x,y)=\frac{-54x^{2}-27x-54y^{2}-108y-89}{2}-\frac{|81x+27 |}{2}
\end{align*}
By definition $\nabla f: \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ over on open set $\Omega$ is defined as $(f_{1},f_{1})\longmapsto \left(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y} \right)$. Then,

- $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}(x,y)=-\frac{27}{2}\left( 4x+1+\frac{81(3x+1)}{|81x+27|}\right)$.
- $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}(x,y)=-54(y+1)$.

So $${\rm Dom} \nabla f=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 81x+27\not=0\}$$
and this answer your first question about the domain of gradient of $f$.

About your another question for the local minimum and local maximum you can use the theorem stated in the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4405749/1027216.

Finally about another question for the global minimum and global maximum you need more information about the domain of $f$ at least check in the problem if there is no additional information about a domain other than all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Because for example setting $x=0$, we get the function does not have lower bound. Also for the critical points you need more information about the domain for $f$.

Comment: There is no additional information about the domain of f. The function indeed has no global minima. It goes to minus infinity. I did the math to find the critical points and found (-1,-1) and (1/2,-1) as local maxima. After evaluating each point at f, I concluded that (1/2,-1) is the global maxima. Is there any flaw in my rationale?